# Plotting the solution of nonlinear 2-dimentional system of ODEs

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear

I am new to Mathematica, and I have a 2-D system of ODEs:
dx/dt=y
dy/dt= -x+x^3-2*m*y

Mathematica code:

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -x[t] + x[t]^3 - 0.2 *y[t] , 
   x[0] == y[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, -1, 1}]
```

```
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. s], {t, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. s], {t, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I want to plot the solution of the system X(t),y(t).
When I use this code nothing appears.
I'll appreciate your help, Warm Regards.

Comment: Post Mathematica code?

Comment: I am sorry, I am trying to put the code, but it appears like plain text. How to include codes here ?

Comment: When we set `{x[0],y[0]}={0,0}`, the result is a segment on x-axis. Maybe change to `{x[0],y[0]}={1,1}` for example.

Comment: I guess you figured it out, but anyway: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. I have another question how can I plot x(t) vs t and y(t) vs t in 2 separate graphs?

Comment: Do you mean `ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, -1, 1}]`?

Comment: This function I think plots the x with respect to y, but I want to plot x with respect to t and also for y.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to solve the odes's to plot the solutions.

Let your first state variable be $x_1=x$ and the second be $x_2=y$. Then your odes are

\begin{align*}
x_1' &= x_2 \\
x_2' &= -x_1 +x_1^3 - 0.2 x_2
\end{align*}

Therefore the command in Mathematica to plot the solution is

```
StreamPlot[{x2, -x1 + x1^3 - 0.2*x2}, {x1, -2, 2}, {x2, -2, 2},
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x(t)", "y(t)"}, 
 StreamPoints -> {{{{1, 1}, Red}, Automatic}}, 
 StreamColorFunction -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The red line shows the solution for initial conditions $(1,1)$. Change as needed.

> How can I plot X(t) vs t and y(t) vs t in 2 separate graphs?

You can do

```
s = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -x[t] + x[t]^3 - 0.2*y[t], 
   x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 3}]

opts = {GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, ImageSize -> 300};
p1 = Plot[s[[1]][t], {t, 0, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"time (sec)", "x(t)"}, Evaluate@opts];
p2 = Plot[s[[2]][t], {t, 0, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"time (sec)", "y(t)"}, Evaluate@opts];
Grid[{{p1, p2}}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. How can I plot X(t) vs t and y(t) vs t in 2 separate graphs?

Comment: @Doaamahmoud updated. Are you sure you want time to run from -1 to 1? Time normally starts at t=0.  But you can change the code above as you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. and I will change the time span to [0 1]